# Cloning data between two objects with a field sorted set Java

Tags: java, set

Ok so i have two classes: Content and TrackUserChanges . They have the same fields.

```
public class Content{
private Long id;
......
private SortedSet<Content> children = new TreeSet<Content>();
}

public class TrackUserChanges{
private Long id;
.....
private SortedSet<Content> children = new TreeSet<Content>();
}
```

I want to clone the data from Content to TrackUserChanges:
I have the children from an instance of content:

```
SortedSet<Content> children = content.getChildren();
```

This can contain many other contents, and that contents can have also children, etc.

```
 SortedSet<TrackUserChanges> children1 = convertContentSetToTrackUserChangesSet(children);
```

This is the method:

```
 public SortedSet<TrackUserChanges> convertContentSetToTrackUserChangesSet(SortedSet<Content> children){
    SortedSet<TrackUserChanges> children1 = new TreeSet<TrackUserChanges>();

    for(Content c : children){
        TrackUserChanges trackU = new TrackUserChanges();
        trackU.setCategory(c.getCategory());
        trackU.setId(c.getId());
        trackU.setBook(c.getBook());
        trackU.setInsertUser(c.getInsertUser());
        trackU.setParent(c.getParent());
        trackU.setParentId(c.getParentId());
        trackU.setRelativeSortOrder(c.getRelativeSortOrder());
        trackU.setText(c.getText());
        trackU.setType(c.getType());
        children1.add(trackU);
    }
    return children1;
}
```

I need somehow to call recusively or something like that... and I can't do `trackU.setChildren(c.getChildren())` because the types don't match :/

@Mifmif

```
try {
                  FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("a.dat");
                  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
                  oos.writeObject(content);
                  oos.close();
                  }
               catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            TrackUserChanges trackUserChanges11 = new TrackUserChanges();
            try {
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("a.dat");
                MyCustomObjectInputStream custom = new MyCustomObjectInputStream(fin);
               // custom.readClassDescriptor();
                trackUserChanges11 = (TrackUserChanges) custom.readObject();
                System.out.println("IDDDDD" + trackUserChanges11.getId());
                custom.close();
                }
               catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

ClassCastException :)

Comment: *cloning* works on objects of the same type. Note that the term *clone* itself means generating a copy of yourself. You cannot expect to copy a potato and get a sweet potato, they could have almost the same fields and structure but they're not the same. You need a mapper to convert an instance of one object into an instance of another object from different types.

Comment: Why not set `Content extend TrackUserChanges` and evreything will be simple

Comment: @Mifmif because `TrackUserChanges` is not `Content`, nor vice versa.

Comment: Maybe it's the simplest solution for this case . trying to do a mapper inculde  many  loop with recursive calls, which cause a nightmare when trying to maintain the code.

Comment: @Mifmif in fact, if you want to track user changes, you should not use this approach at all. This will enable to track the changes for a single class and a real world application could have multiple classes and some fields should not be tracked like dateCreated.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza that is what i am trying to do, but I don't know how to create that mapper :(

Comment: @alex1111 seems that you have found another solution, for  try to double check the value of `name.of.the.package.OldClassName` and `name.of.the.package.NewClassName`  and retry again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes with identical properties that have identical behaviour, separate those fields/behaviour into a separate class and extend that class in your other classes. This should allow you to copy directly between them.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class implements Cloneable. Then just call the function clone of the SortedSet.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on serialization , make both of your class serializable and if you want to go from one class instance to another, serialize your instance into a file , and read it using `MyCustomObjectInputStream` :

```
class MyCustomObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

    public MyCustomObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    protected ObjectStreamClass readClassDescriptor() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectStreamClass resultClassDescriptor = super.readClassDescriptor();

        if (resultClassDescriptor.getName().equals("name.of.the.package.OldClassName"))
            resultClassDescriptor = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(name.of.the.package.NewClassName.class);

        return resultClassDescriptor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem

```
public  TrackUserChanges convertContentToTrack(Content c) {

    TrackUserChanges t = new TrackUserChanges();
    t.setCategory(c.getCategory());
    t.setId(c.getId());
    t.setBook(c.getBook());
    t.setInsertUser(c.getInsertUser());
    t.setParent(c.getParent());
    t.setParentId(c.getParentId());
    t.setRelativeSortOrder(c.getRelativeSortOrder());
    t.setText(c.getText());
    t.setType(c.getType());

    if (c.getChildren().size() == 0) {
        return t;
    }
    SortedSet<TrackUserChanges> childs = new TreeSet<TrackUserChanges>();
    for (Content content : c.getChildren()) {
        childs.add(convertContentToTrack(content));
    }

    t.setChildren(childs);
    return t;

}
```

Thanks anyway :)